# How to pass a date parameter in a SSRS report query string parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to pass a date parameter as per below url. I'm trying this from the browser:

```
http://Server1/ReportServer_SQLTest?/Accounting%20Statements
  &rs:Command=Render
  &rdt=1115
  &prt=187
  &edr=11%2f02%2f2021TO
  &cdr=11%2f02%2f2021TO
  &sdr=11%2f02%2f2021TO
  &ed=11%2f02%2f2021
  &cd=11%2f02%2f2021
  &sd=11%2f02%2f2021
  &Grp=45
  &ReportFormat=consolidated
  &filter1=3
  &event=187
  &StyleOption=1
  &vis_usr=-9999
  &call=51fc7815-18e6-4574-a59a-c8a9d223df64
  &rs:Format=pdf
```

it threw an error

> Default value or value provided for the report parameter 'edr' is not a valid value. (rsInvalidReportParameter)

I tried in various ways passing the `edr` date parameter. Still throws error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. In SSRS **TO** means Today; and **YS** means Yesterday. The SSRS validates if today is 11%2f02%2f2021TO; So I changed as below. I took these parameter values from existing db entries.

```
&edr=11%2f09%2f2021TO
&cdr=11%2f09%2f2021TO
&sdr=11%2f09%2f2021TO
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look like the issue is that your `edr`, `cdr` and `sdr` parameters all have `TO` at the end of the passed value, which is not part of any valid date format that I am aware of.

Comment: I tried removing them as well, no luck.

Comment: @Pandiarajan Have you tried different formats, such as `yyyy/mm/dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd` or `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: yes, I tried that too

Comment: @Pandiarajan When you run the report manually and type in values to the parameters, what exactly are you typing in?  Also, have you trying not encoding the slashes in the URL?

Comment: I solved the problem and posted as an answer here, thanks for supporting.